# Filter query results

Tags: mysql

I have this search query and I would like to filter results based on "folder_restriction" but seem AND clause not filter results.
Where do I do wrong?

```
    SELECT * 
     FROM mod_images
     LEFT JOIN mod_folders 
       ON folder_id = image_folder_id
     LEFT JOIN mod_cats 
       ON cat_id = folder_cat_id                    
    WHERE ((`folder_number` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%')) OR
          ((`titule` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%'))        OR
          ((`description` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%'))   OR
      AND `folder_restriction` = '0'
    LIMIT 2000
```

Comment: OR ('%".$search."%') is always true. It's like saying "WHERE 1"

Comment: Are you getting a error ? because your query syntax seems wrong " OR
AND `folder_restriction` = '0'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT * FROM mod_images
    LEFT JOIN mod_folders ON folder_id = image_folder_id
    LEFT JOIN mod_cats ON cat_id = folder_cat_id                    
    WHERE
     ((`folder_number` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
     (`titule` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR
     (`description` LIKE '%".$search."%' ))
    AND `folder_restriction` = '0'
    LIMIT 2000
```

or try to remove the `OR` at the last:-

```
SELECT * 
 FROM mod_images
 LEFT JOIN mod_folders 
   ON folder_id = image_folder_id
 LEFT JOIN mod_cats 
   ON cat_id = folder_cat_id                    
WHERE (((`folder_number` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%')) OR
      ((`titule` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%'))        OR
      ((`description` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%')))   
  AND `folder_restriction` = '0'
LIMIT 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
     FROM mod_images
     LEFT JOIN mod_folders 
       ON folder_id = image_folder_id
     LEFT JOIN mod_cats 
       ON cat_id = folder_cat_id                    
    WHERE (((`folder_number` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%')) OR
          ((`titule` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%'))        OR
          ((`description` LIKE '%".$search."%') OR ('%".$search."%')))
      AND `folder_restriction` = '0'
    LIMIT 2000
```